# Why is my while loop printing continously in the python IDLE shell

Tags: python

I am trying to write a loop that keeps asking the user for the number of items they bought, only stopping when the user inputs 0 or less. Here is my code:

```
quantity = int(input("Enter the amount of items bought: "))
while (quantity>0):
    print("You bought", quantity, 'items')
```

The problem is that this "print("You bought", quantity, 'items')" keeps printing continuously in the IDLE shell. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You never change `quantity` in the `while` loop, so why would it stop?

Comment: You need to ask them for another quantity inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never actually *changing* the variable inside the loop so, if it enters said loop, it will never exit.

A simple fix is the re-ask within the loop:

```py
quantity = int(input("Enter the amount of items bought: "))
while (quantity>0):
    print("You bought", quantity, 'items.')
    quantity = int(input("Enter the amount of items bought: "))
```

However, that unnecessarily duplicates code. There are many ways to fix that, but the best way is probably using the walrus operator introduced in Python 3.8 (from memory):

```py
try:
    while (quantity := int(input("Enter the amount of items bought: "))) > 0:
        print(f"You bought {quantity} items.")
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid integer.")
```

You'll notice I've also added a check for the user entering an invalid integer, that's to prevent your program ending badly when they do so (and they will, trust me).

You should *always* assume the user of your code is a psychopathic software tester :-)

Comment: I should mention that psychopathic software testers are actually the best kind of software testers :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the snippet given, it seems you haven't changed the variable `quantity` after buying the item. I would suggest removing the loop entirely, if there is a currency value. Try this:

```py
quantity = int(input("Enter the amount of items bought: ")) # Ask for amount bought 
print("You bought"+str(quantity)+" items.") # Buy message
currency-=cost_of_item # Replace cost of item with the cost of what you are buying and currency with the money variable
```

However, you could also try this if you still want to keep the loop inside your code:

```py
quantity = int(input("Enter the amount of items bought: "))
while (quantity>0):
    print("You bought", quantity, 'items') # Same code as before
    quantity=0 # Exit loop
```

Comment: Not sure why you would have a loop if you're going to exit after one iteration? If that's desired, your first suggestion is better.

Comment: There isn't enough context to really get far with the intentions of a loop, but I suppose you could go through an if statement and put the `quantity=0` inside it, and loop that way.

Answer (score 1):

A loop makes code run over and over until it reaches a condition. Your code says

quantity = whatever the user inputs

while quantity is > than 0 print this statement

You're going to need to place the user input inside of your loop so it will say instead

while quantity is smaller than 0
ask a user for input

Comment: Then you can put your print statement outside of your loop so it only reaches it when the condition is met

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
while (quantity>0):
    quantity = int(input("Enter the amount of items bought: "))
    print("You bought", quantity, 'items')
```

This way, you are asking for quantity every iteration.

Comment: Unless `quantity` already exists, that's going to error. And, if it *does* exist but has a non-positive value, the loop will never start. I'd suggest putting `quantity = 1` before the `while` as a possible solution.